# Separating the pdf generation module in Yii

Tags: pdf, yii, components, tcpdf

I am generating a pdf report and adding it as an attachment to email . I am using the tcpdf extension and using the Yii framework. My doubt is where do I place the code to generate the pdf. I can add it to a controller code just before sending email, but I want to create a separate function which when invoked generates a pdf and saves it to disk.

Here is my sample code

```
                $transaction->commit();



                        $mail = Yii::app()->Smtpmail;
                        $mail->IsSMTP();   
                        $mail->IsHTML(true);                                   

                        $mail->SetFrom("do-not-reply@abc.com", 'XXX Admin');
                        //$headers = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8";

                        $mail->Subject = "Confirmation of survey completion";
                        $mail->MsgHTML("Hi $survey->first_name $survey->last_name, <br><br>Thank you for completing the survey. The details of your survey result will be sent to the leader. <br><br>Please contact the leader for further details.<br><br>Regards,<br>Admin, XXX");


                        $mail->AddAddress("abc@gmail.com", "");
                        $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
                        //to invoke another controller/component to generate pdf here
                        $controller1 = new PdfReportController("test");
                        $controller1->actionEnglishReport();
                        $dir = realpath(__DIR__ . '/../runtime/pdf-assets');
                        $file = $dir . '/export.pdf';
                        $mail->AddAttachment($file);   
                        if(!$mail->Send()) 
                        {
                                Yii::log("Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo, 'error','application');
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            Yii::log('Data1 saved!. Mail sent', 'info','application');
                        }
```

I am not very clear about how to separate this pdf generation module. Please help

Update:
I managed to separate the pdf module like this:

```
                  //Pdfreports is a component class which has MandarinReport            as a static method
                 PdfReports::MandarinReport();
                 $dir = realpath(__DIR__ . '/../runtime/pdf-assets');
                 $file = $dir . '/export.pdf';
                 $mail->AddAttachment($file);
```

The problem is though the Pdf is created , the email with the attachment is not sent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at the MVC pattern that Yii uses http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.mvc

the MVC pattern is a widely for developing GUI's and seperates the responsibilities of the code in three different layers if you take a look here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model–view–controller#Interactions) you can see that a controller only can send commands to update the state of a model or view

In Yii a controller should never be instantiated. this is something that Yii will handle for you. its not really clear where your sample code is executed but you could create a Yii component (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.component) for sending the emails and generating the pdf's

```
class mailer extends CComponent{

    public static function sendMail($model){
        // You're mail code
        return $mail->send(); // return true the mail is send
    }

    public static function generatePDF($model){
        // You're mail code
        return $pdf->path; //return the path where the pdf is saved
    }
}
```

You could however take a look at Yii events and behaviors but it's a bit more tricky. (http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/44/behaviors-events/ & http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.component#component-event)

For storing you're pdf you can use the yii asset manager http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/148/understanding-assets/

The reason why the mail is not send could be for a number of reasons check the application log in runtime for errors.